# Can $\sqrt[3]{2}$ be expressed as a linear combination of roots of unity?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

I need to solve the following problem:

Can $\sqrt[3]{2}$ be expressed as a linear combination of roots of unity (with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$)?

I am completely lost because I have no idea of how to start this problem. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: A linear combination with coefficients *where*? In $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Yes in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Your question is answered in the negative  by the arguments given to that linked question. Using roots of unity of varying orders does not help, because you can select $n$ to be the least common multiple of the orders of the roots of unity that you uses, and then apply those old answers.